# GIT commands missing from VS Code

Tags: flutter, git, visual-studio-code

I have installed and updated VS Code to the latest version, and installed Git as well. I am trying to do my first check-in ever.

However, I only see the "changes" list as shown below:

[image]

I do not see the "File History", "Branches", "Remotes" as shown in this picture. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the `GitLens - Git supercharged` extension.  See [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).

It has those views -they aren't built into the native Git vscode extension, you might have to open up the Main Menu/View/Open View to see them all, like `Branches`, `File History`, etc..

Comment: The only extensions I have installed are Dart, FLutter, Gradle for Java, Intellicode, Intellicode API Usage Examples, Material Icon Theme and Pretty XML. I don't have the GitLens extension installed.

Comment: Where did you get your second image then, the one with a Branches view?

Comment: from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiweMDoWhqA

Comment: Well, I bet they had the GitLens extension installed.

Comment: I installed GitLens and now I  see the items like that video!! Thank you, Mark.